# powweb and cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

I am using powweb as hosting provider and cloudflare as free cdn. Its been few weeks since my website is down and it says "website down, no cache version available". 
And to add more to it, I cannot access powweb or any website hosted from powweb from my ISP connection. So i am facing trouble solving my cloudflare issue.

I just wanted to know if the problem I am facing is from cloudflare side or powweb side.
Some time i can access my website from my end but my friend in another country says its down for days.

So is there any suggestion guys?

Comment: my website url is http://jukson.com

Comment: What's the IP address of your host at powweb?

Answer (score 0):

The site in question is loading for me. If your server is up and running fine & you're getting this message, then something is [blocking requests from CloudFlare's IPs](http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/I_keep_seeing_%22My_Site_is_Offline%22) at either your hosting provider or directly from your server. Please make sure CloudFlare's IPs are whitelisted.

"And to add more to it, I cannot access powweb or any website hosted from powweb from my ISP connection. "
If you can't access the site at all (no error messages, just hanging), this sounds like an ISP issue and a traceroute would be helpful to see the network path. You should send the traceroute to the CloudFlare help section on the site.